# How could one implement non removable nor editable content in the lexical editor

Tags: reactjs, lexicaljs

## Context

My use case would require that the user can fill in gaps in a long text. Something similar like you have in language learning textbooks, where you need to fill the gap with the verb in the right tense. Thus only the gaps should be editable. Everything else should stay constant.

Of course, the most straightforward way would be to represent every gap as separate input and the constant text as regular HTML elements, thus getting rid of the need to use a fancy editor library,
This would not be good enough when the input would need to span multiple lines. Either user can not see the entire text or the text alignment would look horrible if I started using multiline text areas.

I initially did this with DraftJs, but I ran into problems when I tested the solution with Android. That is why I am now trying to use Lexical as it is supposed to have good cross-platform support.

## What could be the solution

I am totally new to Lexical, thus I am not sure how to go about this.

If there was a way to intercept every new state of the editor, with the ability to access the content, and a way to disqualify a new state (meaning the editor should not render it and revert to the previous state), then that would be enough. In that case, I could check if the content still has all the non-editable sections and if yes then let the change through if not block it, but I have not found anything like that in the docs.

Maybe there is another way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option to solve this is to create a *decorator node*. They are non-editable by default and use React for rendering their look.

Another option is to override a text node by creating a [custom node](https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/node-replacement) and implementing `updateDOM` function such, that it does not modify anything.

Comment: I think these are both good ideas, but in my case I'd already implemented a whole hierarchy of custom nodes and rewriting them to all use a different kind of TextNode or as decorators would have meant a ton of refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing a solution inspired by Lexical's example of implementing a character limit, where if the user types more characters than allowed, the editor is restored to a previous state - see https://github.com/facebook/lexical/blob/ede18e69a0741d3dc72a14cca4f107ff532763bb/packages/lexical-playground/src/plugins/MaxLengthPlugin/index.tsx

For my particular use case, I instead iterated through the nodes in the `rootNode` and concatenated the text content of non-editable nodes to check that the nodes hadn't been changed. Checking length isn't enough because if the user highlights a character and then types a character, the content will change even though the length is the same, so you need to check content. The transform seems to execute immediately, so there's no jank.

I tried implementing this as a transform directly on my custom type, but the issue is that the type has children and isn't necessarily marked as dirty when its children are edited, so for simplicity I instead just registered a transform on the `rootNode`.

Here's what I ended up with (note that `PromptNode` is my own custom type, replace it with whatever you need to be non-editable and add a `isUneditable` function to your type):

```
export function $getDescendantNodesOfType<T extends LexicalNode>(node: LexicalNode, klass: Klass<T>): T[] {
  let nodes: T[] = []

  if (node instanceof klass) {
    nodes.push(node as T)
  } else if ($isElementNode(node)) {
    for (const child of node.getChildren()) {
      const needle = $getDescendantNodesOfType(child, klass)
      nodes = nodes.concat(needle)
    }
  }
  return nodes
}

export function UneditablePlugin(): null {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    let lastRestoredEditorState: EditorState | null = null;

    return editor.registerNodeTransform(RootNode, (rootNode: RootNode) => {    
      const prevEditorState = editor.getEditorState()

      let prevTextContent = ''
      prevEditorState.read(() =>
        $getDescendantNodesOfType(rootNode, PromptNode)
          .filter((promptNode) => promptNode.isUneditable())
          .forEach((promptNode) => {
            prevTextContent += promptNode.getTextContent()
          }),
      )
      let textContent = ''
      $getDescendantNodesOfType(rootNode, PromptNode)
        .filter((promptNode) => promptNode.isUneditable())
        .forEach((promptNode) => {
          textContent += promptNode.getTextContent()
        })

      if (prevTextContent !== textContent) {
        // Restore the old editor state.
        if (lastRestoredEditorState !== prevEditorState) {
          lastRestoredEditorState = prevEditorState
          $restoreEditorState(editor, prevEditorState)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```